# How to change the search suggestions Text Color

Tags: android, search

I want it to be in black. I tried to change the textPrimaryColor but the search input field was also affected and I don't want that to happen.

[image: Screenshot]

Here's my styles for the Action Bar.

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and found the solution here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5237#c8

**EDIT:**

Try to override the style for the suggested text.

In your "MyActionBar" style add the following item:

```
<item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/AutoCompleteTextViewLight</item>
```

And create the style AutoCompleteTextViewLight which fix the color:

```
<style name="AutoCompleteTextViewLight" parent="@android:style/Widget.AutoCompleteTextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
</style>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: You're completely right @TomBrunberg. I edited the answer adding the details

Comment: Hi, i try the same code but the text still white, do you have any suggestion for this issue? thakns in advance.

Comment: At least for me, this overrides the color of the text in the search box itself, not the suggestion list.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue before and created a work around for it.

```
/**
 * @param viewGroup
 *            View to search for child views inside
 * @param _class
 *            child view class inside the View
 * @return child view of corresponding View class
 */
public static <V extends View> Collection<V> findChildrenByClass(ViewGroup viewGroup, Class<V> _class) {

    return gatherChildrenByClass(viewGroup, _class, new ArrayList<V>());
}

/**
 * @param viewGroup
 *            View to search for child views inside
 * @param _class
 *            child view class inside the View
 * @param childrenFound
 *            child view if found
 * @return child view of corresponding View class
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <V extends View> Collection<V> gatherChildrenByClass(ViewGroup viewGroup, Class<V> _class, Collection<V> childrenFound) {

    for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        final View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (_class.isAssignableFrom(child.getClass())) {
            childrenFound.add((V)child); // unchecked on this line
        }
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            gatherChildrenByClass((ViewGroup) child, _class, childrenFound);
        }
    }

    return childrenFound;
}
```

Here are two methods that find all child views of the `SearchView`, currently, there are three childs for `SearchView`:

- `TextView` which can be seen in the drop down suggestions list
- `AutoCompleteTextView` which you type in inside the `SearchView`
- `ImageView` which is the close image to the right of the `SearchView`

Now, lets find the `TextView` and then change its color. Do this in your `Activity` or `Fragment`:

```
// Setting up the TextView of searchView suggestions drop down list
for (TextView textView : findChildrenByClass(mSearchView, TextView.class)) {
     textView.setHint("Type a word");
     textView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
     textView.setHintTextColor(Color.argb(128, 255, 255, 255));
}
```

All done :)